# Writing a bash script that compares two log files comparing timestamps

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm having trouble figuring out how to match to find matches in two different files when comparing timestamps. The fields I'm wanting to match up are in the format:

Jul 26 09:33:02

I have tried reading the file line by line and using
`awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'` which only gets and stores the timestamp in one of the files. I've been looking around and saw this example:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{!a[$3]++;next }{ b[$3]++ }
END {
 for(i in a) {
  for(k in b) {
   if (a[i]==1 && i ~ k ) { print i }
   }
  }
 }' $FILE $FILE2
```

Which sorta works but its way over my head at the moment. The two files can be found in your /var/log/syslog and /var/log/auth.log (using Ubuntu 11.04)

I looked around for other examples and wasn't able to apply it to my application. 
Thank You

Comment: Unless it needs to be done in bash, you might change the title. Maybe something like "collate timestamps between files". Because you are interested in syslog and auth.log, this might be a good question for serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$FILE` and `$FILE2` contain a list of timestamps and you can format the timestamp in such a way that it is separated from other fields by whitespace:

```
join <(sort -k 1b,1 $FILE) <(sort -k 1b,1 $FILE2)
```

The output will be all the timestamps that exist in both files.

Comment: Just to re-clarify a log entry from syslog would be in the form of: `Jul 26 11:35:44 bdouglas kernel: [70761.603498] usb 2-1.1.4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 12` and an entry in auth.log would be `Jul 26 13:17:01 bdouglas CRON[11888]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root` and what I'm after in the long run is grouping the same timestamp entry from auth.log with an entry from syslog comparing against the time stamp.

Comment: two input redirections.. huh?

Comment: @yi_H that's [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Comment: I posted this in linuxquestions.org and got a pretty decent answer with this: `while read line;
do
    grep "$(echo $line | grep -o '^[[:alpha:]]\{3\} [[:digit:]]\{2\} [[:digit:]]\{2\}\:[[:digit:]]\{2\}\:[[:digit:]]\{2\}')" /var/log/syslog;
done < /var/log/auth.log` I like what I see but its a bit long winded. I was thinking of using awk $3 to get the 3rd field but not to sure about the grep flag I should pass. I see he passed the -o flag which takes the pattern "only matching". I'll have to look into this. Any suggestions?

Comment: @random0munky, those timestamps you show are very different. Do you really want to see a cronological story grouped by user instead?

Comment: @glenn: I just pulled them out of the file at random, there are timestamps which are equal to each other in both of the files.